# Overlay SAS GMAP Choropleths

Tags: plot, maps, sas

Reformulation: I want to overlay the following two Graphs:

```
data mystates;
set maps.states;
myvar = state<30;
run;

pattern1 c=black v=m3n0;
pattern2 c=black v=m3n90;
%let except = (where=(state not in (72,2,15)));
proc gmap map=mystates &except. data=mystates &except.;
   id state;
   choro myvar;
run;
quit;
```

And

```
goptions reset=all;
%let no = 48;
proc gmap map=maps.counties (where =(state=&no.)) data=maps.counties (where =(state=&no.));
   id county;
   choro county;
run;
quit;
```

As the granularity is different I cannot simply use 2 choro statements in teh proc gmap: Note how the order of the two choro statements matters. One always overdraws the other.

```
data mytry;
set mystates &except. maps.county (where =(state=&no.));
run;

pattern1 c=black v=m3n0;
pattern2 c=black v=m3n90;
proc gmap map=mytry data=mytry all;
   id state county;
   choro myvar;
   choro county;

run;
quit;
```

How can I display both the lines and the colors at the same time?

Comment: You might find something you could replicate here: http://robslink.com/SAS/Home.htm. He has tons of examples with code.

Comment: Can you try showing us an example of your code that doesn't work, using the built-in SAS maps?  You definitely can do most if not all of what you're asking just using the built in maps.  I would guess you have to treat it as one dataset, with the counties as polygons and knowing which county-polygon is in which state; ie, to have Texas be shaded vertically lined and New Mexico horizontally lined, take the various counties in Texas (colored variously) and shade all of them vertically, opposite for New Mexico.

Comment: Thanks @itzy for the very useful Link. However I did not find the answer I was looking for there.